# how to unfold objects containing array as field in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am totally new with mongodb requests. I hope you will help me with this problem.

Lets assume that one has an following structure of document:

```
{
       "_id" : 4444,
       "item" : "xyz",
       "price" : NumberDecimal("5.95"),
       "quantity" : 5,
       "products" : [ 
         { "guid" : "www-www-eee", "price" : 200 },
         { "guid" : "www-rrr-eee", "price" : 200 },
         { "guid" : "rrr-www-eee", "price" : 200 }
       ]
}
```

I would like to unfold this object such that its structure would be as following.
Ideally, it should be created an view which related to document. Also new IDs created, where old ones saved also with another name.

```
{
       "_id" : 55555,
       "old_id": 4,
       "item" : "xyz",
       "price" : NumberDecimal("5.95"),
       "quantity" : 5,
       "product" :{ "guid" : "www-www-eee", "price" : 200 }
       },
    
{
       "_id" : 77777,
       "old_id": 4,
       "item" : "xyz",
       "price" : NumberDecimal("5.95"),
       "quantity" : 5,
       "product" :{ "guid" : "www-rrr-eee", "price" : 200 },
       },
    
{
       "_id" : 4,
       "old_id": 4,
       "item" : "xyz",
       "price" : NumberDecimal("5.95"),
       "quantity" : 5,
       "product" :{ "guid" : "rrr-www-eee", "price" : 200 }
}
```

With regards

Comment: see [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage, to deconstruct array

Comment: thanks man, i will $unwind did it. But it has not created new IDs

Comment: it will not create any new id, _id will remain same in all document, if you want to add index id you can use `includeArrayIndex: "field name"` in unwind stage, check unwind documentation